# Randomness inside tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a unique application in tensorflow where I need to randomly sample from a constant tensor while computing the loss function for a neural network (this is different from sampling a batch from training data).

Here's a simplified version:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(batch, nn, const_tensor):
  out = nn(batch)

  random_index = int(tf.random.uniform((1,), maxval=3, dtype=tf.int32))
  random_element = const_tensor[random_index]

  loss = some_function(out, random_element)
```

Is this the "right" way to do this? Does this implementation affect graph execution in any way?